# How to protect android app from pirates

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to protect Android app against theft and modification of app itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482331/how-to-protect-android-app-against-theft-and-modification-of-app-itself)

I'm looking for a ways of how to protect my app from being modified, rebuilded with different mailware codes, thiefing ads id files(in order to ban me from ad network)...

How to protect the source code of app. Please, do not refer to google Proguard, I want something else in addition to this.

Comment: Have you read [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html) I think its useful one. Also [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8482331/940096)

Comment: Thanks @SpK, I found some nice ideas, but still not enough, would like to use something which is already done. Anyway, great thanks )